# Best practice: storing sql statements in mysql database?

Tags: mysql

in most of the free online games now there are always actions needs time to be complete, like for example having to wait for 3 hours for a specific process to complete.
I've managed to make a table with a Endofprocess field and with the first interaction with the server the processes that met the time or passed it gets executed.

THE QUESTION IS:
when the time of the process completion is met, how can I execute a statement like delete or insert or even more than one statement.

the only thing I'm thinking about is to make another field and store the statement that will be executed upon the task completion.

```
 CREATE  TABLE `dbkorsanx`.`TBLPROCESSES` (
 `ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
 `PROCESS_ENDS_AT` DATETIME NULL ,
 `PROCESS_STATEMENT` TEXT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`) );
```

IS THERE A BETTER IDEA FOR THIS?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of saying the query directly, save in the DB what you want to update. It can be a type flag, user_id or someother meta data. If its of variable length save as some json or so

I will have a cron which executes in every n minutes or a service. Based on your logic, the service/script can ran the required queries.